# Messaging Functionality Creating Sql query and Database View

Tags: sql, database, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Given the following:

[image]

I need to be able to get a list of all threads in which a given user has participated, sorted by most recent message first, with only the most recent message being displayed (1 message per thread)

This is the SQL query for the above:

```
SELECT
    Message.MessageId,
    Message.CreateDate,
    Message.Body,
    Login.Username,
    (SELECT MessageReadState.ReadDate
        FROM MessageReadState
        WHERE MessageReadState.MessageId = Message.MessageId
            AND MessageReadState.LoginId = 2) AS ReadState
FROM Message INNER JOIN Login ON Message.SenderLoginId = Login.LoginId
WHERE Message.MessageId IN (
    SELECT Max(Message.MessageId)
    FROM MessageThreadParticipant
    INNER JOIN Message
        ON MessageThreadParticipant.MessageThreadId = Message.MessageThreadId
    WHERE MessageThreadParticipant.LoginId=2
    GROUP BY MessageThreadParticipant.MessageThreadId
)
ORDER BY Message.CreateDate DESC;
```

The way this works is this. a Loginid 1 send a LoginId 2 a message:

1. a new thread is created and a record is inserted into MessageThread
2. a new record is added into Message table with the treadId from above
3. TWO records are inserted into MessageThreadParticipant (Sender LoginId and Recipient LogiId)

   When a user opens his/hers list of messages MessageReadState will update ReadDate of the message.

QUESTION:
I would like to create a view where I can simply filter on LoginId (I would be using LINQ). However I can't do this with the Query above (since i would need to pass loginId somewhere within the sql statement). Is there anyway to modify the above SQL query in such way that would allow me to have a view?? what is it?

EDIT:
i think i have it but i'm not sure if this is the best/most efficient solution:

```
SELECT
    Message.MessageId,
    Message.MessageThreadId,
    Message.SenderLoginId,
    Mtp.LoginId,
    Login.Username,
    Message.CreateDate,
    Message.Body,
    (SELECT MessageReadState.ReadDate
        FROM MessageReadState
        WHERE MessageReadState.MessageId = Message.MessageId
            AND MessageReadState.LoginId = Mtp.LoginID) AS ReadState
FROM Message 
    INNER JOIN Login ON Message.SenderLoginId = Login.LoginId
    INNER JOIN MessageThreadParticipant Mtp ON Mtp.MessageThreadId = Message.MessageThreadId
WHERE Message.MessageId IN (
    SELECT Max(Message.MessageId)
    FROM MessageThreadParticipant
    INNER JOIN Message
        ON MessageThreadParticipant.MessageThreadId = Message.MessageThreadId
    WHERE MessageThreadParticipant.LoginId=Login.LoginID
    GROUP BY MessageThreadParticipant.MessageThreadId
)
ORDER BY Message.CreateDate DESC;
```

Comment: You need the loginId to be a field in the top-level select, i.e. remove the various `.LoginId = 2` parts, include LoginId in the select list and join appropriately.

Comment: In MessageThreadParticipant, how do you determine which LoginID is the sender, and which is the recipient?

Comment: When you want to filter by LoginID, are you filtering by the Sender or the Recipient?  Or perhaps both?

Comment: 1. MessageThreadParticipant -> lists just participants, Message table has a field called "SenderLoginid" 2. I just want a list of All message threads (with the most recent message within a thread) per a given LoginId.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this do something like what you want?

```
SELECT
  Login.LoginID,
  Login.Username,
  Message.MessageThreadID,
  Message.MessageId,
  Message.CreateDate,
  Message.Body,
  Sender.LoginID                     AS SenderLoginID,
  Sender.Username                    AS SenderUsername,
  MessageReadState.ReadDate          AS RecipientReadDate
FROM
  Login
INNER JOIN
  MessageThreadParticipant
    ON MessageThreadParticipant.LoginId = Login.LoginID
-- This gives all threads every LoginID has ever participated in

CROSS APPLY
  (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Message WHERE ThreadId = MessageThreadParticipant.MessageThreadId ORDER BY CreateDate DESC) AS Message
-- This gives the newest message for each of those threads.
-- The Login.LoginID could be either the Sender or Recipient

INNER JOIN
  Login AS [Sender]
    ON Sender.LoginID = Message.SenderLoginID
LEFT JOIN
  MessageReadState
    ON  MessageReadState.MessageID = Message.MessageID
    AND MessageReadState.LoginId <> Sender.LoginID
-- This gets the Sender's details, and tries to get whether the recipient read the message
-- It assumes the only MessageReadState entries are for the Sender and Recipient.

ORDER BY
  Message.CreateDate DESC;
```

Comment: almost there. ReadDate should be null for LoginId 2 and it's not. (I only have 1 record in MessageReadDate with a valid date for Sender) Recipient hasn't read the message yet.

Comment: The current code chooses the `MessageReadState` record for the Recipient as being (This message, but not the Sender's LoginID).  Do you have a cleaner way to identify the correct record?  *(Does the Message table have a RecipientLoginID field, for example?  You may be advised to include the schema for these table, so we know what we're working with.)*

Comment: i think this works: LEFT JOIN
  MessageReadState
    ON  MessageReadState.MessageID = Message.MessageID
    AND MessageReadState.LoginId = Login.LoginID

Comment: Login.LoginID isn't necessarily the Recipient, it could be the Sender.