# Question about relating participants to a MessageThread

Tags: sql, t-sql, email

I am trying to implement a messaging system. I am trying to include all the Users(recipients) into a MessageThread as UserID as shown in the picture. While it seems to work, I figured out that the UserID in MessageThread (as a foreign key) can only relate to specific User in the Users table. I am trying to see if I can include all the Users at once when a new MessageThread is started instead of inserting MessageThread with same MessageThreadID for multiple times(think of it like there are 100 participants...). I am thinking of replacing UserID with array of UserID but do not know if it is a common way to do it.

[ERD of Messaging System](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXtD1.png)

MessageThread has a MessageThreadID as Primary key and UserID as a foreign key relating to Users table. When I join the MessageThread table and Users table, I should be able to get detail User info of a participated User like UserName, FirstName, etc .

***Updated:***

I followed this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver16#Benefits) as recommended. I created table type called **ThreadParticipantsTableType** with UserID as attribute and a stored procedure called **up_insert_MessageThread** to insert Threads.

For the last step of this guide, it told me to declare a variable  and inserting data into the table(to be insert into **up_insert_MessageThread** procedure). Since data to be insert is UserID(recipient) and it is to be entered by sender, so I created another procedure called **addThreadParticipants** to add UserIDs to the table and to execute **up_insert_MessageThread** to insert a thread. After execution, nothing changed to the MessageThread table. I wonder if there is something I did wrong?

```
Create type ThreadParticipantsTableType as table
(
    UserID int
);
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[up_insert_MessageThread]
(
    @TVP ThreadParticipantsTableType READONLY
)

AS

INSERT INTO dbo.MessageThread
select * from @TVP

return

Alter procedure dbo.addThreadParticipants
(
    @UserID int
)
AS


DECLARE @ThreadParticipantsTVP AS ThreadParticipantsTableType;

INSERT INTO @ThreadParticipantsTVP (UserID)
   values (@UserID)

/** for sample execution **/
EXEC dbo.addThreadParticipants @UserID=111111;

EXEC dbo.up_insert_MessageThread @ThreadParticipantsTVP;

return
```

Comment: What semantics do you want? If you look back at an old message thread that included "all" users should it include users added more recently? what about deleted users? This may be a case where implementing an interface through stored procedures (SPs) and table-valued functions (TVFs) would help. You could use a TVF to `GetUsersForMessageThread( MessageThreadId )` that recognizes a value of `NULL` for `UserId` to mean "all users" and returns the appropriate users. If it should take `CreatedDate` into account you can hide it in the SPs/TVFs and not have to worry about it in every query.

Comment: @HABO I think my logic is like the following. When user compose a new Message, it will generate a new MessageThread object and the new Message is associated with MessageThread object using the foreign key MessageThreadID. 

In order to be able to determine the recipient(s) of the Message, I used the foreign key UserID to relate Users object(s) that I want to relate to. It seems to make sense when I drew my ERD by hand... But when I tried to write stored procedure for inserting a new MessageThread with UserID(multiple recipients), I found that I can only input 1 UserID per MessageThread.

Comment: I just carefully reviewed ShaneKm's design https://stackoverflow.com/q/6621895/9389213. It seems like when a new MessageThread is created, a new row would be inserted alone with for a single UserID. In other words, if there are 3 participants(recipients) for MessageThread 1, 3 new rows would be inserted into MessageThread table. For example, row 1: [MessageThread 1, UserID 1], row 2: [MessageThread 1, UserID 2], row 3: [MessageThread 1, UserID 3]

Comment: You could use a [table-valued parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver16) to pass multiple `UserId` values in a single call to the SP. Whether the SP stores multiple rows in a table, encodes it into a single XML mess in one row, or saves it in mystic runes hewn into the living rock isn't an issue the caller needs to worry about. Just the rest of the SPs and TVFs. Aside: Part of the value of providing an interface is letting you block direct access to the tables.